# Problema con el filtro de busqueda PHP

Tags: php

Buenas tardes necesito su ayuda lo que me sucede es lo siguiente, yo estoy haciendo un filtro de búsqueda en php, este filtro se realiza por fecha de compra, fecha de gestion, compra y la mascota, mi problema radica en que cuando filtro solo por una fecha no me arroja nada pero si filtro por mas de dos campos ahi si me filtra.
Este es mi query

```
SELECT a.id,a.cedula,a.empresa,a.apellido_paterno,a.apellido_materno,a.nombres,a.telefono_1,a.telefono_2,a.celular_1,a.celular_2,a.frecuencia,a.preferencia
        FROM        usuarios a
        left join factura f on a.cedula=f.cedula
        left join gestion g on g.idcliente=a.id
        WHERE ( ".$s1."
             ".$s2."
             ".$s3."
             ".$s4.")
        ORDER BY a.cedula DESC
        limit 50
```

para poder realizar la consulta y asignar las variables hago las siguientes validaciones:

```
if($mascota != 1):
        $s1=" a.mascota = '".$mascota."'";
        else:
        $s1=" ";
    endif;
    if($compra != 1 && $mascota == 1):
        $s2="f.producto like '%".$compra."%'";
    else:   if ($compra != 1) :
            $s2="and f.producto like '%".$compra."%'";
            else:
            $s2=" ";
            endif;
    endif;
    if($fecha_gestion != 1 && $mascota == 1 && $compra == 1):
        $s3="CAST(g.dateat AS DATE) = '".$fecha_gestion."'";
    else:   if ($fecha_gestion != 1) :
            $s3="and CAST(g.dateat AS DATE) = '".$fecha_gestion."'";
            else:
            $s3=" ";
            endif;
    endif;
    if($fecha_compra != 1  && $mascota == 1 && $compra == 1 && $fecha_gestion == 1):
        $s3="f.fecha = '".$fecha_compra."'";
    else:   if ($fecha_compra != 1):
            $s3="and f.fecha = '".$fecha_compra."'";
            else:
            $s3=" ";
            endif;
    endif;
```

ya llevo rato tratando de encontrar el error pero aún no lo consigo encontrar porque es raro que cuando sólo filtre por fecha_compra o fecha_gestion no arroja nada pero si busco por ejemplo por fecha_compra y por mascota ahí si arroja datos.
Espero me ayuden muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar esto en tu clausula `WHERE`:

```
WHERE (1=1 ".$s1."
         ".$s2."
         ".$s3."
         ".$s4.")
```

Luego solo tienes que chequear si las variables estan definidas o no y agregar el `AND`.  Ejemplo:

```
if($mascota != 1):
    $s1=" AND a.mascota = '".$mascota."'";
endif;
if($compra != 1):
    $s2=" and f.producto like '%".$compra."%'";
endif;
```

Comment: pana no se como agradecerte he estado un buen rato dando vueltas en esto y esa era la solucion aunque me gustaria que me expliques porque no me salia la consulta y agregandole el 1=1 si. Igualmente millones gracias

Comment: Sirve para simplificar.  Sabemos que 1 siempre va a ser igual a 1, o sea que la primera condicion siempre se va a cumplir.  Eso te sirve para que todas las demas condiciones empiezen con un `and` sin importar cuantas variables esten definidas.

Comment: ok listo muchas gracias, uno nunca termina de aprender ...